# Python-geoJSON producing invalid JSON output

Tags: python, json, geojson

I am using python-geojson 1.0.9 and for some reason the output json it produces is invalid. I've tried to use it on my google maps API, doesn't work. I've checked it through geojson.io which similarly that it is not valid.

Am I using the library wrong? Or is this a problem with the library?

My Python Code is below:

```
DATABASE FORMAT
1. ROW 0 = node_number
2. ROW 1 = latitude
3. ROW 2 = longitude
4. ROW 3 = time
5. ROW 4 = water_level

dict = {}
print "\n Show me the databases: \n"
for row in rows:
        dict[row[0]] = {'latitude' : str(row[1]), 'longitude' : str(row[2]), 'time' : str(row[3]), 'water_level' : str(row[4]), 'node_number' : str(row[0])}

print dict

nodeCount = 0
plist=[]
flist=[]
for node in dict:
        #Cast our GPS coords into floats
        lat =  float(dict[node]['latitude'])
        lon = float(dict[node]['longitude'])
        print "\n Point = %d : Lat = %f Long = %f" % (nodeCount,lat,lon)

        #Increase nodeCount
        nodeCount += 1

        # Generate point and add to point list
        point = Point((lon,lat))
        plist.append(point)

        # Generate feature and add it to feature list
        feature = Feature(geometry=point, properties={"nodeNumber": dict[node]    ['node_number'], "waterLevel": dict[node]['water_level'], "time": dict[node]['time'], "longitude": dict[node]['longitude'], "latitude": dict[node]['latitude']})
        flist.append(feature)

# Generate Feature Collection and dump to file
FeatureClct = FeatureCollection(flist)

#Encode FeatureCollection as JSON
dump = geojson.dumps(FeatureClct, sort_keys=True)
print dump
with open("output.json", "w") as text_file:
    text_file.write("%s" % dump)
```

And here is the JSON output I get: http://104.236.77.88/bostonunderwater/geojson/
Note that the eqfeed_callback( JSON ) is a wrapper I manually put around it, and that the JSON still isn't valid even with it removed.

Any possible direction you can give as to why I'm generating invalid JSON would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GeoJSON in that link (without the wrapper) is valid. You can check for yourself here: http://geojsonlint.com/ Just copy/paste into the textarea and don't forget to click "FeatureCollection" in the top navbar first. It's also valid when i run it through http://jsonlint.com/ It must be something sketchy with http://geojson.io/ because your GeoJSON is perfectly fine.

Comment: geojson.io seems to be complaining about the id field having to be a string or a number. So maybe the geojson standard supports null as a valid entry but geojson.io doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps the Google Maps API is choking over the same issue. How would I add an id property to a feature?

Would it be like:
Feature(geometry = point, properties = {xxxxxxxxx}, id = id_val)   ???

EDIT: answered my own question, the above syntax works

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the specification that states what the type of the feature property id must be. The only thing stated about the identifier is this:  "If a feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier should be included as a member of the feature object with the name "id"." That's it, nothing more. Reference: http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects So they're being too strict at geojson.io

Comment: Issues filed: https://github.com/mapbox/geojson.io/issues/412, https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7648 Curious on what they'll have to say on the matter.

Comment: Problem solved: they're using https://github.com/mapbox/geojsonhint at geojson.io, which is written against the draft spec which states: "If a feature has a commonly used identifier, that identifier SHOULD be included as a member of the feature object with the name "id" and the value of this member is either a JSON string or number." https://github.com/geojson/draft-geojson/blob/master/middle.mkd#feature-object